# Prove surjection on Complex numbers

Tags: functions

Let

> $$f:\begin{cases}\mathbb{C}^*\to\mathbb{R}^*_{+}\\ z\mapsto|z|\end{cases}$$

Prove that $f$ is surjective.
$|z|$ is defined as $\sqrt{z*\overline{z}}$ whereas $\overline{z}$ is the complexe conjugate. I have to prove that for all z $\in$ $\mathbb{C}^*$ there exists some  $|z|$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}^*_{+}$ so that $f(z) = |z|$ right?

So, now to prove the claim I take an arbitrary $z \in\mathbb{C}^*$ and then what?

Comment: Hi, just a pro-tip:  you don't need to include each individual thing in the \$ braces, you can just write all the math in a row between a single set of them.

Answer (score 2):

Take an arbitrary positive real $x$ and find a $z$ so that $f(z) = x$.

Hint:  if $x$ is as above, what's $f(x)$?

Comment: In this case f(x) is just z I guess.

Answer (score 1):

$R^*_+\subseteq\Bbb C^*$, and $\sqrt{x\cdot\bar{x}}=|x|$ for $x\in\Bbb R$. So this function is the identity on $\Bbb R^*_+$, proving surjectivity.